# Unable to found -lGL, how to do without symlink?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, ld

I'm compiling a shared library, with a `-lGL` on the ld command. But it can't find the libGL.so on my system. Nvidia package correctly set libraries path in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`.
Even the output of `ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so` found it:

```
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so.1
libGL.so (libc6,x86-64, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libGL.so
libGL.so (libc6, OS ABI: Linux 2.4.20) => /usr/lib32/libGL.so
libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libGL.so
```

I read almost everywhere that to be able to link with it, i have basically 2 solutions:

1. Link the nvidia libGL.so to a standard /usr/lib location. That seem wrong for anybody what will try to compile an opengl library. Why the linker is not using the ldconfig cache ?
2. Append manually the -L/usr/lib/nvidia-current to the library search path. Again, wrong, how can i know every path where the library could be found on all the system ?

So my real question is: What is the standard and automatic approach for linking with a library not in a standard location, but location already register with `/etc/ld.so.conf` ?

Comment: Sorry, i'm doing python extension. Removing the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/ld.so.conf` is used by `/lib/ld.so` to resolve shared libraries at runtime, it has nothing to do with linking stuff at compile time.

What is the right way to do is just linking to `libGL.so` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and the application will use the nvidia's `libGL.so` on runtime. This shouldn't be a problem because the OpenGL interface is stable and symbols are the same in both libraries, its the implementation that is different.

Comment: Ok, so i'm on a standard linux, i must add myself -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu ? What about other platform ? (32 bits, and other linux ?) Nothing generic ?

Comment: On a normal Linux machine 32bit version is in `/usr/lib` and 64bit version is in `/usr/lib64`

Comment: Yes so that is not sufficient for found automatically libGL (by the way, it's not in /usr/lib32 and /usr/lib ?)

Comment: -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu is not supposed to be needed, since Debian, which uses this multilib directory scheme, should have patched their linker to already search there. Nope, what you need is a libGL.so in the dirs searched by your linker, and that is usually provided by the Mesa(-devel) package(s).